# How to properly clear an object array in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, arrays

I know this question has already gotten alot of answers here but these solutions are not working for me, maybe i'm doing something stupid but i don't quite understand what exactly is wrong with my code. Also is it good to save temporary data in a object array and then later send it to a database using ajax and php??

I'm doing a multi step form and i need to save data inbetween steps.

From the code you can see i tried different solutions to clear the object but none of them worked. Also when i check the length it's always 0 so that means the object is empty. What am i missing here?

Every time i check the console log the previous data is still there(check the image).

[image]

My code

```
$(document).on('click', '.e-check', function(){
  $('.e-check').text('check_box_outline_blank');
  $('.e-check').removeClass('e-checked');
  $(this).text('check_box');
  $(this).addClass('e-checked');
  var edata = '';
  edata = {};
  edata = undefined;
  console.log(edata.length);
  edata = {
    'ename' : $(this).data('ename'),
    'owner' : $(this).data('owner'),
    'estart' : $(this).data('estart'),
    'eid' : $(this).data('eid'),
    'eat' : $(this).data('eat'),
    'sec' : $(this).data('sec'),
    'pid' : $(this).data('pid')
  };
  $(document).on('click','.e-next-1', function(){
      console.log(edata);
  });
});
```

Comment: You are creating a delegate binding inside another delegate binding.  Don't do that.  Pull it out to be on it's own so it's not re created over and over.  The previous bindings are going to repeat with the old `edata` variable every time the e-next-1 is clicked which is why you are seeing old data

Comment: Clearly you dont understand scoping in javascript. You are comparing two variables with the same name but with different values. Read more: http://ryanmorr.com/understanding-scope-and-context-in-javascript/

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I'm sorry i was just trying to clear the object with different solutions i found online :D

Comment: @Taplar I don't quite understand what you mean by that?? When i pull
$(document).on('click','.e-next-1', function(){
      console.log(edata);
  });
out of the function then it says that edata is not defined.

Comment: @Taplar ohh damn, i understand now. Thank you for helping me out.

Comment: @JasperSeinhorst I'll check this link out and educate myself, thank you!

Comment: I've improved your code below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a scoping issue. You need to declare a variable globally to mutate the variable. You could do something like this:

```
var edata = '';

$(document).on('click', '.e-check', function(){
  $('.e-check').text('check_box_outline_blank');
  $('.e-check').removeClass('e-checked');
  $(this).text('check_box');
  $(this).addClass('e-checked');
  edata = {};
  edata = undefined;
  console.log(edata.length);
  edata = {
    'ename' : $(this).data('ename'),
    'owner' : $(this).data('owner'),
    'estart' : $(this).data('estart'),
    'eid' : $(this).data('eid'),
    'eat' : $(this).data('eat'),
    'sec' : $(this).data('sec'),
    'pid' : $(this).data('pid')
  };
});

$(document).on('click','.e-next-1', function(){
    console.log(edata);
});
```

Note the var edate = ''; part is outside the click callbacks, so it is globally accessible

Comment: oh wauw, i missed the part about inner binding. I will update the answer

Comment: @Taplar is right. I took the other binding out of the function and it fixed my problem.